# PostgreSQL - problem with INSERT trigger enabled when performing COPY FROM STDIN bulk insert (hangs/locks)

Tags: postgresql, trigger

So I work with a database that regularly imports a significantly amount of records- on the orders of millions. To do this the most efficient way possible, I use the PostgreSQL `COPY FROM` method, which is well documented to be the fastest way for a bulk load. I am aware of *fast* ways to load this data, but with *really* large sets it's orders of magnitude faster to use the `COPY FROM` method. I am doing it from Python3/psycopg2 so I can actually stream it from memory and use `STDIN`, without needing to write to disk. This all works great... until recently.

A colleague added an `INSERT` trigger to one of the tables that I perform these bulk loads on. Once this trigger was added/enabled, the bulk loads simply hang. No resources seem to be spinning on the server.

This specific load normally take about 5-10 seconds to complete, but in this case remains hung, and looking at pgadmin4 indicates there's some sort of transaction lock on my `COPY FROM` operation. Using `strace` on the client side shows that it has sent a bunch of `sendto()` operations, but it is waiting for a response. Finally, after a bunch of `sendto()` it just stops and is idle, on (if I remember correctly) a `select()`, waiting for action on the socket.

Can anyone help me to understand why this behaves this way? It appears that the trigger does not fire (which makes sense, I think, since there are no `INSERT` statements in the `COPY FROM`) and I don't see any obvious errors in the logs. There are also no errors on the client-side.

Disabling the trigger using `ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER trigger_name` allows me to perform the load as before, in about 5 seconds. Re-enabling it then brings back the same issue.

I haven't found documentation saying that these two are fundamentally incompatible. So what the heck is going on? Am I missing documentation? Am I going to have to ditch the `COPY FROM` approach and go back to regular `INSERT` batches? Is there a workaround (aside from implementing the trigger a batch job, which is not desired)

I would love to understand the low-level details as well as how to fix or work-around this.

Thanks for the help

EDIT: The trigger looks like this:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM asi_ip_geolocation WHERE ip_address =ANY(new.ip_address); 
  INSERT INTO asi_ip_geolocation (ip_address, country_code, country_name, region_name, city_name, latitude, longitude, block)
  SELECT ip.ip, country_code, country_name, region_name, city_name, latitude, longitude, block 
  FROM asi_inventory, 
  UNNEST(NEW.ip_address) AS ip 
  LEFT JOIN asi_ip2location_geo ON ip.ip << asi_ip2location_geo.block 
  GROUP BY ip.ip, country_code, country_name, region_name, city_name, latitude, longitude, block
  ORDER BY block DESC
  LIMIT 1;  
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

The table being bulk loaded is `asi_inventory`. The `asi_ip2location_geo` table contains information to map IP addresses to geopgraphic locations.

Looking at `pg_stat_activity`, I do not see the trigger firing, the only relevant query I see is the `COPY`:

```
 asi-dba | (null)          | (null)     | active |   647802417 | COPY asi_inventory ("cname", "ip_address", "fqdn", "resolver", "source", "source_list", "capture_date", "fqdn_root") FROM STDIN WITH CSV
```

I also see several `ROLLBACK` queries:

```
 Client          | ClientRead          | idle   |      (null) | ROLLBACK
 Client          | ClientRead          | idle   |      (null) | ROLLBACK
 Client          | ClientRead          | idle   |      (null) | ROLLBACK
```

Comment: So  what does this trigger do? Did you check `pg_stat_activity` if your process was waiting on some lock maybe?

Comment: I added the trigger to the original post. I agree that it seems like a locking issue. I am not very familiar with `pg_stat_activity` but I do see in the dummy friendly `pgadmin4` a mention of a transaction lock/locked. Let me take a look at `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: Added some more details

Comment: That trigger is indeed going to be a problem as it will be fired for each row that is inserted into the asi_inventory table. It might help to re-write that trigger to a statement level trigger rather than a row level trigger. Then it would fire only once, rather then a million times

Comment: We'd need to see the complete `pg_locks` view from the hang.

Comment: As far as triggers are concerned, COPY is a form of INSERT.  Since the triggers are invoked as part of the COPY by the same backend process running the COPY, they will not be visible in pg_stat_activity apart from the COPY entry.  It looks like you have diagnosed "hang" only on the client side, so it is probably just slow, not hung.